# Do you need mutex for a class/struct if mutex is managed by members?

Tags: c++, class, mutex

So if I pass a variable by reference/pointer between threads I should either implement a mutex or use std::atomic (I know there's other options).  But what if I instead pass a class containing members that are std::atomic or have corresponding mutex members and wish to access the member variables?

Example:

```
//class.h
#include<mutex>
#include<atomic>
class MyClass {
    Public:
        std::atomic<int> i;
        double d;
        std::mutex dmutex;
        MyClass();
    Private:
        ~MyClass();
}


//main.cpp
#includ<mutex>
#include "class.h"

void ThreadFunction (MyClass &myclass) {
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        myclass.i++;
        myclass.dmutex.lock();
        myclass.d += 0.5;
        myclass.dmutex.unlock();
    }
    return;
}

int main () {
    MyClass commonclass;
    std::thread t_thread1 (ThreadFunction, commonclass);
    std::thread t_thread1 (ThreadFunction, commonclass);
}
```

OR

```
//main.cpp
#includ<mutex>
#include "class.h"

void ThreadFunction (MyClass &myclass, std::mutex &mymutex) {
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        mymutex.lock();
        myclass.i++;
        myclass.d += 0.5;
        mymutex.unlock();
    }
    return;
}

int main () {
    MyClass commonclass;
    std::mutex commonmutex;
    std::thread t_thread1 (ThreadFunction, commonclass, commonmutex);
    std::thread t_thread2 (ThreadFunction, commonclass, commonmutex);
    t_thread1.join();
    t_thread2.join();
}
```

Lets talk in terms of only accessing member variables (my concern now) and then  member functions, assuming they modifiy these member variables and handle mutexing accordingly.  Is one more right than the other?  Is second unecessary?

Comment: Case1 is correct (except the fact that mutex/variables are public, that `lock_guard` is better than manual locking).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing things up here: Using stuff as a public member does not change anything. You're just taking an extra way over the *this*  Pointer deference.

I comes down to the essence: If two threads are changing data which isn't atomic by itself, they must synchronize via, for instance, a mutex.
Both cases are regarding to synchronization the same.

---

**Supplemental**: Better think in operations: Changing a nonatomic variable are multiple operations in machine code. `std::atomic`s are only helping in regard that hey offer common operations which are or seem to be atomic, by for example using special machine instructions for comparinging and changing a value in one atomic machine step. But more complex operations like "change this atomic, and with that value change this other data and do this", and these operations are dependent on each other, than you have to protect that by a mutex. And the best way is to name this, now by the mutex, atomic operation and put it into a method like described below.

---

A class could help you by making `d` and its mutex private and only changing and reading it by readers and setters, which are doing the mutex handling for you. I.e. the concept of encapsulation. `std::atomic` does exactly this on platforms, where it's not lock free.

But you loop will be really slow, so an `std::atomic` would still be the best.

**Short: Both cases are wrong** (regarding good practices )

You class should roughly look like this

```
#include<mutex>
#include<atomic>

class MyClass {
public:
    std::atomic<int> i;
    MyClass() = default; //you could also just spare this line because you don't declare other constructors
    double d() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> d_guard(dmutex);
        return this->d_;//this-> is not needed
    }
    void setd(double d) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> d_guard(dmutex);
        d_ = d;
    }
    void add_to_d(double to_add){
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> d_guard(dmutex);
        d_ += to_add;
    }
private:
    double d_;
    std::mutex dmutex;
};


void ThreadFunction (MyClass &myclass) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        myclass.i++;
        myclass.add_to_d(0.5);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good info.  So if I understand correctly, if I was not using atomic variables and had a mutex (like d), it would be a better practice to create a getd function that does the mutex lock/unlock for me and then I can leave the mutex private?

Comment: Yes. See my added code. Add member functions for more complex transactions which could be done concurrently.

Comment: Sorry. You updated your answer while I wrote the comment.  Ok, that confirms what I thought.  I guess additionaly we could overload the math operators for the functions for d and it we could be ignorant of the mutex all together?

Comment: @NateGreco No overloading the math operators is just a fancy name for the functions.

Comment: @NateGreco Checkout the supplemental I added

Comment: What should be done if I have multiple threads that access the d() and setd(). One of the threads will do a setd(1) followed by a ASSERT(d() == 1). Since the mutex is within the functions themselves (d() and setd()) it might happen that in between the operations some other thread might setd(2) and ASSERT would fail. Should the mutex be made public then?

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't use class with a number of `std:atomic<T>` variables because it won't guarantee you consistence of them:

Let say you have a class like that:

```
class A{
    std::atomic<int> a1, a2, sum;
public:
    void update(int a1, int a2){
        this->a1 = a1;
        this->a2 = a2;
        this->sum = a1 + a2;
    }
};
```

There is possible race condition in `void update`: one thread had changed `a1` and `a2` and was stopped, second thread did the same and sum, first thread woke up and rewrited sum with old value.

So only way to provide consistence for complex structures - is to use `mutex`.

Comment: Well like I said, don't we need to differentiate between classes without modifier functions?  What if it was a class of only std::atomic variables, or better yet, a structure of all std::atomic variables?  I wouldn't need a mutex for the structure, would I?

Comment: @NateGreco You still need `mutex` because it doesn't matter if members are changed in member or non-member function, isn't it obvious? If your class members depend on each other you HAVE TO block entire object to make changes.

Comment: Ok, I understand, you're right.  I was thinking in terms of my application where the class is really just a means for me to pass by reference common variables and are not dependent on each other at all.  I guess in that case the solution above is valid but once the members depend on each other like your example the entire class must have a mutex.  Interesting.